# In excel, how can you search for text matching multiple column entries?

Tags: excel

Currently in excel, I have columns and rows that look like the following:

```
           Person 1 Person 2    Person 3    Person 4    Person 5
Condition 1      F       T             F           F           F
Condition 2      F       T             T           F           F
Condition 3      F       F             T           T           F
Condition 4      F       F             F           F           T
Condition 5      F       F             F           F           F
```

For each person, they have a 5 valued vector of True/False entries for each of 5 conditions. Currently, I have about 50 people, and it becomes a nightmare to manually find the ones matching a 5 valued vector I want. For example, I would like to find the Person matching FTTFF, which is person 3.

I am wondering if there is a way in excel to quickly identify which columns contain the string, read vertically? thanks.

Comment: A quick hack but `Concatenate` the values for each person in the row below and then Find (Ctrl + F) the specific string? Personally I'd transpose everything, create a helper column concatenating the True/False values, and then filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to add another column which would be concatenation of columns 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 (use the & sign to concatenate text)
so for person 3 you'd get FTTFF and for person 1 you'd get FTFFF
and then you filter by that new column

Comment: Note that OP wants the concatenation of the values vertically (by person, not condition), so not across columns. This won't work unless you transpose all of the data.

Comment: @BigBen Yes I mean row. In order to filter you need to copy the table and make the rows columns (you can transpose the data easily by coping and choosing the option of "transpose")

Comment: Which is basically what I proposed already... I'm just saying that you need to note that you transpose the data beforehand.

Comment: You could also just use `Transpose`, without copying.

Comment: @BigBen cool I didn't know that you can use transpose without copying! thanks!